# Serializable Inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

If something inherits from a Serializable class, is the child class still Serializable?

Comment: Also, this question is ambiguous

Answer (score 90, accepted):

It depends what you mean be serializable. If you mean the CLI marker (i.e. the `[Serializable]` attribute), then this is *not* inherited (proof below). You must explicitly mark each derived class as `[Serializable]`. If, however, you mean the `ISerializable` interface, then yes: interface implementations are inherited, but you need to be careful - for example by using a `virtual` method so that derived classes can contribute their data to the serialization.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(Foo).IsSerializable); // shows True
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(Bar).IsSerializable); // shows False
    }
}

[Serializable]
class Foo {}

class Bar : Foo {}
```

Comment: Attributes, by their nature, are not inherited.  Also, a class can not be considered to inherit from an attribute.  Ergo, attributes have nothing to do with the OP's question.

Comment: Sorry, but you are wrong. Attributes *do* relate to the question; the [Serializable] attribute is one of those that the compiler handles differently: it uses this to set the "serializable" flag on the CLI class (if you check the IL, it actually throws away the attribute at this point).

Comment: Equally, I never said anything about the class inheriting from an attribute - although actually, since attributes *are* classes, and attributes can inherit from each-other, an attribute class very-much inherits from an attribute...

Comment: Nice point about the derived classes. I ended up here looking for this exact explanation.