# serializable to derived classes

Tags: c#, serializable, derived-class

Is there an easy way to enforce a derived class must be serialiable?

Suppose I define a interface that needs the derived classes to be serializable. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182873/serializable-inheritance), I cannot just specify the serializable attribute in the interface, because derived classes don't need to respect that.

I believe I could have the interface inherit from the ISerializable interface, but does that mean that the derived class couldn't use the attribute to specify serialization (as opposed to actually implementing the methods for ISerializable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- We cannot use `[Serializable]` as
  gives error with an interface.
- We may use `[Serializable]` attribute
  with `base` class but even then this
  attribute is not inherited. This does
  not seem possible.

Have a look a this link as well.

- [**Enforcing serializable from an
  interface without forcing classes to
  custom serialize in C#.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360208/enforcing-serializable-from-an-interface-without-forcing-classes-to-custom-serial)

Comment: No problems, next time. Thanks for information, have made editions.