# C# Serialization/Inheritance

Tags: c#, serialization, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serializable Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182873/serializable-inheritance)

Is serialization inheritable?

Example:

```
[Serializable]
class A
{
}

class B : A
{
}
```

If I try to serialize/deserialize an instance of class B, I get an exception stating that the class is not marked as serializable.  Thus the question:  is serialization inheritable?  Am I just missing how to do it, or does every class that needs to be serialized require explicitly being marked as such?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's [*not* inheritable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0(v=VS.100).aspx):

> It is important to note that the Serializable attribute cannot be inherited. If you derive a new class from MyObject, the new class must be marked with the attribute as well, or it cannot be serialized.

You should mark the subclass as well to make it serializable:

```
[Serializable]
class B : A  {  }
```

Comment: Minor note; *in this case*, the `Inherited` property of this attribute is not directly relevant (although it does happen to be correct). This is because at the metadata layer, `[Serializable]` is ***not*** implemented as an attribute, but as a CLI class flag (you can check this in the IL stream).

Comment: Thanks for the note Marc, it's surely _not_ minor!

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Changed the text and removed that property reference... Thanks